# MongoDB with Play Framework using Java

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia, playframework-2.4

I'm new to Play framework. I'm trying to configure MongoDB database as a datasource to be used with Play framework 2.4.
   But I am unable to find any tutorial or steps which can guide me to have connection of my "Hello world" application with mongoDB. I just need to know how can I use mongoDB with the current play version? 
Just need to understand the basic CRUD operations b/w mongodb and play framework using java (not scala).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PlayJongo Play 2.4.x Module](https://github.com/alexanderjarvis/play-jongo).

It is a Play 2.4.x Module for [Jongo](http://jongo.org/) (a MongoDB Java driver wrapper).

Answer (score 1):

see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11754368/5034081

it explains how to add the java driver for your application. 
but you have to be careful because interacting with database is a blocking action and if you block your threads you will have troubles. read the official doc on how to solve this problem. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ThreadPools

there is also other libs like this for using mongo in a play application.
https://github.com/vznet/play-mongo-jackson-mapper

Comment: Thank you for the useful information.
  I have read about MongoDB Jackson Mapper Plugin (Java). The connection is also established between application and mongodb.
using this link -
[link](https://github.com/Mironor/Play-2.0-Java-MongoDb-Jackson-exemple)
But here the version is 2.0..So will it work for play2.4?
And interaction of jackson with mongodb is non -blocking??

Comment: the link you provided has the version 2.3.1. i think it should work fine with 2.4, not sure. NO interaction with db is blocking and you have to do your db calls in another thread and return a Promise object for the main thread.

Comment: It gives me this error...(No Idea Why...?)

    ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) Could not find a suitable constructor in play.modules.mongodb.jackson.MongoDBPlugin. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
  at play.modules.mongodb.jackson.MongoDBPlugin.class(MongoDB.scala:163)
  while locating play.modules.mongodb.jackson.MongoDBPlugin

Comment: i think the plugin doesn't support 2.4 version since it uses guice for dependency injection. you can ask the plugin owner to migrate it to 2.4 version.

Comment: Yes it is not compatible with the current play version...
[found here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/K7IrXyXvL8w).
You have any other idea.. which plugin to use??

Comment: How about using Reactivemongo?? It is scala driver for mongodb.
But can I use it for java?

Comment: i don't think you can use reactivemongo in java. there is another [lib](https://github.com/alexanderjarvis/play-jongo) but it's for play 2.3 too. you can use play 2.3 or use the java mongo driver with play 2.4.

Comment: For jongo and morphia - I have to create a abstraction layer to use it. Same is the case with reactive mongo (If i want to use it with java). I need to write a wrapper for them. [found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30599490/play-framework-2-4-x-used-with-mongodb-and-java-8).
So i am just beginning with this.Can you provide some links or ideas to understand it better?